# Как у дочернего класса спрятать свойство которое есть у родителя?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, vb.net

Например у родителя есть такое свойство

```
Public ReadOnly Property Attributes() As List(Of ElementAttribute)
    Get
        Return Me._attributes
    End Get
End Property
```

Пытался переопределить его например `Private` или `Protected` но клиентский код свободно может обращаться к родительскому свойству.

```
Protected Overloads ReadOnly Property Attributes() As List(Of ElementAttribute)
    Get
        Return Me._attributes
    End Get
End Property
```

Как быть?

Comment: @Kison а при чем тут C#-то? В вопросе код на VB.NET :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полностью спрятать его невозможно - всегда же можно привести тип к родительскому, и чтобы ни было написано в дочернем классе - на родительские свойства это не повлияет.

Чтобы скрыть свойство рекомендательно (к примеру, как ненужное) - можно воспользоваться атрибутом [`System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Обращение к скрытому этим атрибутом свойству все еще возможно - но из IntelliSense свойство пропадет.

Также можно применить к свойству атрибут [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) - в таком случае обращение к свойству вызовет появление предупреждения при компиляции.

Comment: `<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>` Не работает! в IntelliSense как было так и есть :) 2015 студия.

Comment: `ObsoleteAttribute` Работает и выдает предупреждение, мол свойство не рекомендуется использовать, тут все ок.

Answer (score 3):

Необходимость сузить функционал наследника по сравнению с базовым классом говорит о возможных проблемах в дизайне.

Наследование говорит об отношении "ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ" между базовым классом и наследником, а это означает, что все, что применимо для базового класса, должно выполняться и наследником.

**В этом случае, это означает, наследник не может (по определению) сузить интерфейс базового класса и убрать открытый член из списка видимых.**

Тут есть несколько вариантов:

1. Убрать свойство из базового класса и перенести его в наследник, для которого оно применимо (очевидно, что помимо представленных в вопросе двух классов, должен быть как минимум еще один для которого свойство `Attributes` не должно скрываться.
2. Бросать исключение в одном из наследников.

Первый вариант ведет к более чистому дизайну, поскольку он четко говорит о том, что некоторое свойство доступно не для всех типов иерархии, а лишь для его подмножества.

Второй вариант переносит ошибку со времени компиляции во время выполнения и может привести к большому удивлению со стороны пользователей класса.

В свое (?) оправдание, могу сказать, что второй функционал активно используется на практике. Коллекции являются хорошим примером: readonly-коллекции наследуются от не-readonly-коллекций и бросают исключения при вызове методов-мутаторов.

Но я бы использовал второй вариант только в том случае, если изменить базовый класс нельзя или число наследников, для которых это свойство применимо существенно привышает число наследников, для которых оно не применимо.